# React Native - initialProperties Android

Tags: javascript, android, objective-c, properties, react-native

I'm working under React-Native and I'm looking for passing initial props to JS via Java. This can be done easily in Objective-C with initialProperties like this :

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"myapp"
                                               initialProperties:initialProperties
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Where initialProperties is an `NSDictionary` which will be converted in JSON and available in JS via `this.props`.
So I'm looking to do the same in Android. Any help ? Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Android, you can pass `initialProps` in with the `launchOptions` as a Bundle.

As is mentioned here in the source code: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7377fdcc70b25eb023e7c6d1b37eeae2a700cb88/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactRootView.java#L325-L334

So you can do something like this:

```
Bundle initialProps = new Bundle();
initialProps.putString("myKey", "myValue");

mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MyAwesomeApp", initialProps);
```

Comment: This works wonderfully. Why are the other answers talking about `ReactActivityDelegate`?

Comment: Is is possible to pass in structured data, similar to the way in which you can pass in an NSDictionary of values to React Native in iOS? Or are scalar values only possible?

Answer (score 13):

getlauchOptions has been moved inside ReactActivityDelegate, now I use this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

/**
 * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
 * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
 */
@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "myAppName";
}

@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
            Bundle initialProps = new Bundle();
            initialProps.putString("SOME_VARIABLE_1", BuildConfig.SOME_VARIABLE_1);
            initialProps.putString("SOME_VARIABLE_2", "some variable 2 value");
            return initialProps;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Should add that you need to add at the top `import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;` and by default `@Nullable` is not available in RN. I just dropped it, assuming it means I just need to always pass a value.

Comment: could you add @ssomnoremac comments in your response ? They are easily unseen

Answer (score 7):

update for react-native > 0.59.0 you need override ReactActivityDelegate in your `MainActivity.java`

Example

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;

public class RNTesterActivity extends ReactActivity {
  public static class RNTesterActivityDelegate extends ReactActivityDelegate {
    public RNTesterActivityDelegate(ReactActivity activity, String mainComponentName) {
      super(activity, mainComponentName);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
       // YOUR PROPS
       Bundle props = new Bundle();
       props.putString("key1", "string");
       props.putInt("key2", 5);
       return props;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new RNTesterActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName());
  }

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "RNTesterApp";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All the answers here seemed a bit out of date. With React-Native 0.42 this worked for me.

In your Activity (not Application) class do this

```
@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, "My Cool App") {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            if( MainActivity.this.port != null ) {
                bundle.putInt("port", MainActivity.this.port);
            }
            return bundle;
        }
    };
}
```

Obviously replace "port" with whatever you want to pass to the props of your main React Native Component

Comment: Does this still work in react-native v.0.55? I am quite new to Android development and I am unsuccessfully trying to implement this. I added your code and the projects builds without any errors. App runs as it is suppose to, but no props get passed...

Answer (score 3):

As of react-native v0.20, you can override the `getLaunchOptions` method in the `MainActivity.java` file.

```
@Override
protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
  Bundle opts = new Bundle();
  opts.putBoolean("someValue", true);
  return opts;
}
```

This will allow you to access `someValue` from your main app component's props:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    someValue: PropTypes.bool,
  };

  render() {
    return <SomeComponent someValue={this.props.someValue} />;
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

Answer (score 3):

Be careful, this is deprecated in react-native > 0.34

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/9320

this is the commit message :

```
Move `getLaunchOptions` from ReactActivity to ReactActivityDelegate
Summary:
After 3c4fd42, `getLaunchOptions` no longer exists in class `ReactActivity`.
We need refactor UIExplorerActivity to fix the build error.
Closes #9320

Differential Revision: D3696381

Pulled By: astreet

fbshipit-source-id: 5700cf2363029a95cfbdaf6230e4f82ea69fb472
master (#2)  v0.34.0-rc.0
```

Thus you'll need to change this part of your code if you update your version of react, and since you're overriding a method which will not exist in the parent class you might not get into any error message and it'll be hard to debug

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13661616)

Comment: right, I edited my answer to show the commit message