# React Native: How can I detect if my code is running in the Simulator?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In a Obj-C iOS app I can use `#if (TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)` to write simulator-only code.

In react native I can use:

```
if (__DEV__) {
 .. do something special
}
```

.. to detect development mode.

We can use `Platform.OS === 'ios'` to detect the platform (Android/iOS).
See here for more info [Platform Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html)

But how do we detect if the app is running in the simulator?

The reason I ask is that my app uses the camera to scan barcodes, and this isn't supported in the iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info), like so:

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'

isSimulator() {
  // https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info#isemulator
  return DeviceInfo.isEmulator();
},
```

Comment: Does .getModel() has the same result on android as well? which is "Simulator"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, I haven't done much with Android! Great question!

Comment: This does not work on android simulators (at least in mine)

Comment: Use DeviceInfo.isEmulator() instead. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @BrunoLemos I don't think your edit was saved/accepted

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLemos, I've updated the answer. I see that this was indeed added to RNDI in https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/commit/0021bb10c2f147c5fd9eb403473db106a29cd65f. Cool!

Comment: This is kind of awkward because it uses promises for something that should just be a value.

Comment: @ICW Yeah that's just the way it is for react-native-device-info. I assume they have a good reason, like maybe getting this value requires accessing the filesystem (which is inherently an async operation). ‍♂️

Answer (score 31):

The easiest solution I can think of, which does not require creating a native module (or modifying an existing one), would be to pass this parameter as a react component property.

In your `AppDelegate` where the `RCTRootView` is initialized, you check if it's the simulator as you would do in a regular iOS app; you then pass this info to the react root-view as its `initialProperties`:

```
  BOOL isSimulator = NO;
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
  isSimulator = YES;
#endif
  
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"ReactDemo"
                                               initialProperties:@{@"isSimulator": @(isSimulator)}
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Now you can access it in the JavaScript via the props of your react component:

```
this.props.isSimulator
```

On Android, in you `MainActivity` which extends `ReactActivity` you can use a similar approach:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

public boolean isEmulator() {
        return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
                || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
                || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
                || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
    }

@Override
protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
    Bundle opts = new Bundle();
    opts.putBoolean("isEmulator", isEmulator());
    return opts;
}
```

Comment: Hey, great solution and it works like a charm. Do you also have a code snippet on how this would work with Android?

Comment: @SebastianGermesin I updated the answer to show a solution for Android using a similar approach.

Comment: In latest RN (0.63.x), [using `createReactActivityDelegate` works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57606851/152711).

Comment: I also needed to add a line like this: `|| Build.MODEL.contains("sdk_gphone")`

Comment: For ios how can I access value isSimulator in functional component? as it doesn't have 'this'

Answer (score 22):

If you're building a CRNA/Expo app you can use `Device.isDevice`
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/device/#deviceisdevice

```
import * as Device from 'expo-device';
//....

console.log(Device.isDevice) // => false if simulator
```

Comment: this is now `Device.isDevice` from this import: `import * as Device from "expo-device";` and `Constants.isDevice` is deprecated: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/device/#deviceisdevice

Comment: works fine for the iOS simulator but not for android

Answer (score 7):

Using [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) you can get the following data (executed on a simulator):

```
getUniqueID: DB71DCB5-6BB0-497B-BE9E-A02BCC1235B7
getInstanceID: undefined
getDeviceId: x86_64
getManufacturer: Apple
getModel: Simulator
getBrand: Apple
getSystemName: iOS
getSystemVersion: 10.1
getBundleId: org.reactjs.native.example.project
getBuildNumber: 1
getVersion: 1.0
getReadableVersion: 1.0.1
getDeviceName:MacBook Pro
getUserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.2.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14B72
getDeviceLocale: en
getDeviceCountry: US
getTimezone: America/Panama
isEmulator: true
isTablet: false
```

Comment: useful information, thanks. Now avoiding to read documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there isn't any way to see if you are running from a simulator in JS.

I would suggest to add the conditional `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` to check in your native code (if you wrote your own module). Or perhaps use a 3rd party module that doesn't render the camera if in a simulator...ie: react-native-camera: https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR

Answer (score 0):

```
import getHostForRN from 'rn-host-detect';
const IS_SIMULATOR = getHostForRN('127.0.0.1') == "localhost";
```

This works to differentiate my iOS simulator from my actual device because the simulator returns `localhost` and the iOS device returns `127.0.0.1`. Have not tested it on Android but let me know if it helps you guys.