# React-Native Android - Get the variables from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, react-native

I'm using intent to start my React-Native app, and I'm trying to find out how to get the variables I put on my intent in the react native code. Is this possible from within react-native or do I have to write some java code to get it?

the code I use to start the app :

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   Intent.putExtra("alarm",true);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What isn't working with `getIntent` on the second activity?

Comment: The second activity is react-native. So my question is how do I get getIntent in react-native.

Answer (score 11):

Try this to get Intent params at react-native app.

In my native App, I use this code:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.my.react.app.package");
launchIntent.putExtra("test", "12331");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

In react-native project, my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "FV";
}

public static class TestActivityDelegate extends ReactActivityDelegate {
    private static final String TEST = "test";
    private Bundle mInitialProps = null;
    private final
    @Nullable
    Activity mActivity;

    public TestActivityDelegate(Activity activity, String mainComponentName) {
        super(activity, mainComponentName);
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = mActivity.getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey(TEST)) {
            mInitialProps = new Bundle();
            mInitialProps.putString(TEST, bundle.getString(TEST));
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
        return mInitialProps;
    }
}

@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new TestActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName());
  }
}
```

In my first Container I get the param in this.props

```
export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log('App props', this.props);

        //...
    }
}
```

The complete example I found here:
http://cmichel.io/how-to-set-initial-props-in-react-native/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass initial props as a bundle to the third parameter in the `startReactApplication` method, like so:

```
Bundle initialProps = new Bundle();
initialProps.putString("alarm", true);

mReactRootView.startReactApplication( mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", initialProps );
```

See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34226172/293280

Answer (score 1):

I think this more correct way based on answer of @Eduardo Junior

```
class MainDelegate(activity: ReactActivity, mainComponentName: String?) :
    ReactActivityDelegate(activity, mainComponentName) {

    private var params: Bundle? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        params = plainActivity.intent.extras
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?): Boolean {
        params = intent?.extras
        return super.onNewIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun getLaunchOptions() = params
}

class MainActivity : ReactActivity() {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
     * rendering of the component.
     */
    override fun getMainComponentName() = "example"

    override fun createReactActivityDelegate(): ReactActivityDelegate {
        return MainDelegate(this, mainComponentName)
    }
}
```