# How to know if the app is open from the android notification tray?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-push-notification

How to know if the app is open from the android notification tray? For instance, I have closed the app (cleared from recent app list). but I receive notification from the backend websocket, i pressed it, it opens the app. So my question is, is there way to check if this is open from notification?

Comment: I've never used react native but instinct would be to use putExtra() when creating the intent and check for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351650/react-native-android-get-the-variables-from-intent

Comment: can you show me the snippet where you configured react-native-push-notification

Comment: did you tried my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple, you receive notifications payload in your push notification listener

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification'
configurePushNotifications = () => {

    PushNotification.configure({
      // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
      onRegister: function(token) {
        console.log('PushNotification token', token)
      },
```

onNotification is where you would receive you local or remote notification and it will be called when the user clicks on notification tray

```
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log('notification received', notification)
      },

      // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      },

      // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
      // default: true
      popInitialNotification: true,

      /**
       * (optional) default: true
       * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
       * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
       */
      requestPermissions: true,
    })
  }
```

this is how the notificaion object would look like

```
{
    foreground: false, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was received in foreground or not
    userInteraction: false, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was opened by the user from the notification area or not
    message: 'My Notification Message', // STRING: The notification message
    data: {}, // OBJECT: The push data
}
```

Comment: hey there, thanks for the advice. Yup, I am using this lib. Turns out, I have to put it at App.js whenever the app is not launch. Before this, I registered the push notification in the app's home page (after login and granted credentials.). But still, i am skeptical and not so comfort with such workaround.

Comment: Why are you skeptical, this is how it should be implemented, we have implemented the listener same as you have. BTW if the answer helped you an upvote would be a kind gesture. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source of [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/aaf2d19925db4666d6018c0ab1ff0d7d4c90a21d/android/src/main/java/com/dieam/reactnativepushnotification/modules/RNPushNotificationHelper.java#L275) + next 50 lines (up to `setContentIntent`) you can check for the "notification" extra in the intent.

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("notification");
        if(bundle != null){
            //check if it is the bundle of your notification and do your thing
        }
    }
```

Otherwise you can use a Native Module approach:

When you set up the `PendingIntent` that you pass into the notifications `.setContentIntent()` method specify an action that you then recover in the application. Example notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.setAction("OPEN_MY_APP_FROM_NOTIFICATION");
NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))            
mNotificationManager.notify(Notification_REQUEST_CODE,
                                    mNotifyBuilder.build())
```

in MyActivity.java

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action == "OPEN_MY_APP_FROM_NOTIFICATION"){
         //do whatever you have to do here
    }
}
```

Additional info:
[Handling intents](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)
[Creating Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent)

Comment: He's using react native.  There's a level or two of indirection between him and a PendingIntent

Comment: True, but as far as I know you have to do that in a [native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android). correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes, but he's using a specific library to do the native module for him.  This is the right answer in native code.  But the answer for him is either a way to use the library to make this happen, or that he has to throw out the library and do it himself.

Comment: I dont know all the steps he has to take in between, but I know this. Feel free to use my answer to provide the whole way.

Comment: @GabeSechan I added some more info, does that help?